# HTTPS stop file upload

Tags: .htaccess, https, prestashop

I'm using PS 1.6.1.1.

I have a file upload when customers are on cart.

The customer can transform cart to quotation and upload this quotation.

But my HTTPS stops the file upload. 
Do you know if I can add exception for

```
http[s]://myshop.com/commande
```

in htaccess?

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/commande
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/commande
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, the upload method is with Ajax or PHP?

Comment: I'm using script PHP

Comment: Any idea @Addis ?

Comment: You have enabled the developer mode? to see if returns some error.

Comment: No error, the processus works but the file is not uploaded